# Select from xml file stored procedure running infinitely returning thousands of duplicate records

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, xml-namespaces, xquery-sql

[image]

I have this stored procedure which returns a lot of duplicate records due to wrong cross apply i suppose. Take a look at the screenshot of result set. Case number 000110-54-3 is only hexane but I get other chemical names related to other case numbers also listed for the same case number. Thus, the query runs forever for other cross\outer apply. Any help appreciated.

XML file catalog item (it's kinda large one)

```
<ArrayOfCatalogItem xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <CatalogItem Version="1">
    <Container xmlns="http://3ecompany.com/webservices/catalogitemxml">
      <ContainerSize>
        <Value>10.500000000</Value>
        <Units>OunceUS</Units>
      </ContainerSize>
      <ContainerType>Unknown</ContainerType>
      <MarkedForRetail xsi:nil="true" />
    </Container>
    <Documents CultureCode="en" Elink="https://3eonline.com/ImageServer/ImageViewer.aspx?id=3Q%2ffAR8ne%2fvPh6syVnSymkS%2bBDo8OjmbVocxRCMEgeENagNJzc81tOXY0yL87aEPfwnzvlaVmM1mbrA2r7BYXNzA43I%2baZTLYlibHjHcCDI%3d" Format="Msds" DocumentType="Sds" Country="USA" DocumentId="SDS8672822" RevisionDate="2015-05-18T00:00:00" xmlns="http://3ecompany.com/webservices/catalogitemxml" />
    <IsHazardous xmlns="http://3ecompany.com/webservices/catalogitemxml">true</IsHazardous>
    <ManufacturerName xmlns="http://3ecompany.com/webservices/catalogitemxml">Permatex Inc.</ManufacturerName>
    <Msds xmlns="http://3ecompany.com/webservices/catalogitemxml">
      <Elink>https://3eonline.com/ImageServer/ImageViewer.aspx?id=3Q%2ffAR8ne%2fvPh6syVnSymqIuIP5CInA01ZbaRQ9r18GfjipRC2KgVeHKeJd2rplH4f%2b5u6E0coedMiZYmt%2fs1A%3d%3d</Elink>
      <FireCodeClassification>
        <Asphyxiant>false</Asphyxiant>
        <WaterReactive xsi:nil="true" />
        <Hmis Chronic="true" Fire="4" Health="2" Reactivity="0" Special="X" />
        <Nfpa Fire="4" Health="1" Reactivity="0" Special="" />
        <Sara>
          <Delayed>true</Delayed>
          <Fire>true</Fire>
          <Immediate>true</Immediate>
          <Pressure>true</Pressure>
          <Reactivity>false</Reactivity>
        </Sara>
        <DerivedPhysicalState>Aerosol</DerivedPhysicalState>
      </FireCodeClassification>
      <Ingredients>
        <ChemicalName>Hexane</ChemicalName>
        <Cas>000110-54-3</Cas>
        <Percent>30.000000</Percent>
        <PercentMin>10.000000</PercentMin>
        <PercentOperator>LessThanOrEqualTo</PercentOperator>
        <PercentMinOperator>GreaterThanOrEqualTo</PercentMinOperator>
        <PercentUnits>ByWeight</PercentUnits>
        <PercentModifier xsi:nil="true" />
        <MinPercent>10.000000</MinPercent>
        <MaxPercent>30.000000</MaxPercent>
        <Sara313Details>
          <ChemicalKey>110543</ChemicalKey>
          <Deminimus />
          <IsPBT>false</IsPBT>
          <IsSara313Toxic>true</IsSara313Toxic>
          <ReportingThreshold>
            <Value>25000</Value>
            <Units>Pound</Units>
          </ReportingThreshold>
          <SaraChemName>N-HEXANE</SaraChemName>
        </Sara313Details>
        <Sara302Details>
          <ChemicalKey>110543</ChemicalKey>
          <IsSara302Ehs>false</IsSara302Ehs>
        </Sara302Details>
        <OshaPelDetails>
          <ChemicalKey>110543</ChemicalKey>
          <OshaPelChemName>N-HEXANE</OshaPelChemName>
          <Type>Z1</Type>
          <Twa>500</Twa>
          <TwaUnits>unknown unit type</TwaUnits>
          <TwaInMg>1800</TwaInMg>
          <Stel xsi:nil="true" />
          <CeilInPpm xsi:nil="true" />
          <CeilInMg xsi:nil="true" />
          <PeakInPpm xsi:nil="true" />
          <PeakInMg xsi:nil="true" />
        </OshaPelDetails>
        <AcgihTlvDetails>
          <ChemicalKey>110543</ChemicalKey>
          <AcgihTlvChemName>N-HEXANE</AcgihTlvChemName>
          <SkinDesignation>true</SkinDesignation>
          <Sensitizer>false</Sensitizer>
          <SimpleAsphyxiant>false</SimpleAsphyxiant>
          <CarcinogenCategory />
          <YearKnowCarcinogen />
          <ExposureByAllRoutes>false</ExposureByAllRoutes>
          <Twa xsi:nil="true" />
          <TwaInPpm>50</TwaInPpm>
          <StelInPpm xsi:nil="true" />
          <StelInMg xsi:nil="true" />
          <CeilInPpm xsi:nil="true" />
          <CeilInMg xsi:nil="true" />
          <MolecularWeight>86.18</MolecularWeight>
          <TlvBasisCriticalEffect>CNS impair; peripheral neuropathy; eye irr</TlvBasisCriticalEffect>
        </AcgihTlvDetails>
        <AvgPercent>20.000000</AvgPercent>
      </Ingredients>
      <Ingredients>
        <ChemicalName>2-Propanone</ChemicalName>
        <Cas>000067-64-1</Cas>
        <Percent>30.000000</Percent>
        <PercentMin>10.000000</PercentMin>
        <PercentOperator>LessThanOrEqualTo</PercentOperator>
        <PercentMinOperator>GreaterThanOrEqualTo</PercentMinOperator>
        <PercentUnits>ByWeight</PercentUnits>
        <PercentModifier xsi:nil="true" />
        <MinPercent>10.000000</MinPercent>
        <MaxPercent>30.000000</MaxPercent>
        <Sara313Details>
          <ChemicalKey>67641</ChemicalKey>
          <IsPBT>false</IsPBT>
          <IsSara313Toxic>false</IsSara313Toxic>
        </Sara313Details>
        <Sara302Details>
          <ChemicalKey>67641</ChemicalKey>
          <IsSara302Ehs>false</IsSara302Ehs>
        </Sara302Details>
        <OshaPelDetails>
          <ChemicalKey>67641</ChemicalKey>
          <OshaPelChemName>ACETONE</OshaPelChemName>
          <Type>Z1</Type>
          <Twa>1000</Twa>
          <TwaUnits>unknown unit type</TwaUnits>
          <TwaInMg>2400</TwaInMg>
          <Stel xsi:nil="true" />
          <CeilInPpm xsi:nil="true" />
          <CeilInMg xsi:nil="true" />
          <PeakInPpm xsi:nil="true" />
          <PeakInMg xsi:nil="true" />
        </OshaPelDetails>
        <AcgihTlvDetails>
          <ChemicalKey>67641</ChemicalKey>
          <AcgihTlvChemName>ACETONE</AcgihTlvChemName>
          <SkinDesignation>false</SkinDesignation>
          <Sensitizer>false</Sensitizer>
          <SimpleAsphyxiant>false</SimpleAsphyxiant>
          <CarcinogenCategory>A4</CarcinogenCategory>
          <YearKnowCarcinogen />
          <ExposureByAllRoutes>false</ExposureByAllRoutes>
          <Twa xsi:nil="true" />
          <TwaInPpm>250</TwaInPpm>
          <StelInPpm>500</StelInPpm>
          <StelInMg xsi:nil="true" />
          <CeilInPpm xsi:nil="true" />
          <CeilInMg xsi:nil="true" />
          <MolecularWeight>58.05</MolecularWeight>
          <TlvBasisCriticalEffect>URT &amp; eye irr; CNS impair</TlvBasisCriticalEffect>
        </AcgihTlvDetails>
        <AvgPercent>20.000000</AvgPercent>
      </Ingredients>
      <MsdsId>8672822</MsdsId>
      <MsdsMfgName>Permatex USA</MsdsMfgName>
      <MsdsProductName>118Da All Purpose Spray Adhesive 11 oz</MsdsProductName>
      <Properties>
        <PhysicalState>Aerosol</PhysicalState>
        <BoilingPoint>
          <Minimum xsi:nil="true" />
          <Range>EqualTo</Range>
          <Units>Celsius</Units>
          <Value>38.0000</Value>
        </BoilingPoint>
        <FlashPoint>
          <Minimum xsi:nil="true" />
          <Range>EqualTo</Range>
          <Units>Celsius</Units>
          <Value>-18.0000</Value>
        </FlashPoint>
        <MolecularWeight xsi:nil="true" />
        <Ph xsi:nil="true" />
        <SpecificGravity>0.7300</SpecificGravity>
        <VaporDensity xsi:nil="true" />
        <Uel xsi:nil="true" />
        <Lel xsi:nil="true" />
        <BoilingPointInCelsius>
          <Minimum xsi:nil="true" />
          <Range>EqualTo</Range>
          <Units>Celsius</Units>
          <Value>38</Value>
        </BoilingPointInCelsius>
        <FlashPointInCelsius>
          <Minimum xsi:nil="true" />
          <Range>EqualTo</Range>
          <Units>Celsius</Units>
          <Value>-18</Value>
        </FlashPointInCelsius>
        <BoilingPointInFahrenheit>
          <Minimum xsi:nil="true" />
          <Range>EqualTo</Range>
          <Units>Fahrenheit</Units>
          <Value>100.4</Value>
        </BoilingPointInFahrenheit>
        <FlashPointInFahrenheit>
          <Minimum xsi:nil="true" />
          <Range>EqualTo</Range>
          <Units>Fahrenheit</Units>
          <Value>-0.399999999999999</Value>
        </FlashPointInFahrenheit>
      </Properties>
      <RevisionDate>2015-05-18T00:00:00</RevisionDate>
      <MsdsRevListId>3836824</MsdsRevListId>
      <SdsConfirmationDate>2015-05-18T00:00:00</SdsConfirmationDate>
      <ClassificationCompleted>true</ClassificationCompleted>
      <CasCompleted>true</CasCompleted>
      <PropertiesCompleted>true</PropertiesCompleted>
      <Locale>en</Locale>
      <DocumentFormat>Msds</DocumentFormat>
      <Country>USA</Country>
      <MsdsLanguage>en</MsdsLanguage>
      <MsdsRegion>UnitedStates</MsdsRegion>
      <SdsNotRequired>false</SdsNotRequired>
      <MfgContactInfo>
        <MfgAddress>6875 Parkland Boulevard</MfgAddress>
        <MfgCity>Solon</MfgCity>
        <MfgState>Ohio</MfgState>
        <MfgCountry>United States</MfgCountry>
        <MfgPostalCode>44139</MfgPostalCode>
        <MfgPhoneCountryCode />
        <MfgPhoneAreaCode>440</MfgPhoneAreaCode>
        <MfgPhoneNumber>914-3571</MfgPhoneNumber>
        <MfgPhoneExtension />
        <MfgFaxCountryCode />
        <MfgFaxAreaCode>440</MfgFaxAreaCode>
        <MfgFaxNumber>914-3500</MfgFaxNumber>
        <MfgFaxExtension />
        <MfgEmail>denise.boyd@permatex.com</MfgEmail>
        <MfgWebUrl>http://www.permatex.com</MfgWebUrl>
      </MfgContactInfo>
      <GhsClassification>
        <SignalWord>None</SignalWord>
        <SignalWordText>Danger</SignalWordText>
        <Pictograms>
          <Code>GHS02</Code>
        </Pictograms>
        <Pictograms>
          <Code>GHS07</Code>
        </Pictograms>
        <Pictograms>
          <Code>GHS08</Code>
        </Pictograms>
        <HazardClasses>
          <HazardClassText>Flammable aerosol.</HazardClassText>
          <CategoryText>Category 1</CategoryText>
          <HazardClassPhraseTextID>92876</HazardClassPhraseTextID>
          <CategoryPhraseTextID>93598</CategoryPhraseTextID>
          <InternalHazardClassPhraseID>4059</InternalHazardClassPhraseID>
          <InternalHazardClassPhraseLangCode>en</InternalHazardClassPhraseLangCode>
          <InternalCategoryPhraseID>4082</InternalCategoryPhraseID>
          <InternalCategoryPhraseLangCode>EN</InternalCategoryPhraseLangCode>
        </HazardClasses>
        <PCodes>
          <SequenceNumber>401</SequenceNumber>
          <Pcode>P405</Pcode>
          <PcodeText>Store locked up.</PcodeText>
          <PcodeSubTypeText>Storage</PcodeSubTypeText>
          <PcodePhraseTextID>91288</PcodePhraseTextID>
          <InternalPcodePhraseID>4009</InternalPcodePhraseID>
          <InternalPcodePhraseLangCode>EN</InternalPcodePhraseLangCode>
        </PCodes>
        <HCodes>
          <SequenceNumber>1</SequenceNumber>
          <Hcode>H315</Hcode>
          <HcodeText>Causes skin irritation.</HcodeText>
          <HcodeSubTypeText>HealthHazard</HcodeSubTypeText>
          <HcodePhraseTextID>91544</HcodePhraseTextID>
          <InternalHcodePhraseID>4017</InternalHcodePhraseID>
          <InternalHcodePhraseLangCode>EN</InternalHcodePhraseLangCode>
        <SignalWordPhraseTextID>236050</SignalWordPhraseTextID>
        <InternalSignalWordPhraseId>22738</InternalSignalWordPhraseId>
        <InternalSignalWordPhraseLangCode>EN</InternalSignalWordPhraseLangCode>
      </GhsClassification>
      <TransportationClassificationCompleted xsi:nil="true" />
      <WasteCompleted xsi:nil="true" />
      <ExtendedSds>false</ExtendedSds>
      <TransportationExceptionClassificationCompleted xsi:nil="true" />
      <BestAvailable>false</BestAvailable>
    </Msds>
    <ProductIdentifiers xmlns="http://3ecompany.com/webservices/catalogitemxml">
      <Identifier>M007628</Identifier>
      <Source>CPN</Source>
      <FirstExportDate xsi:nil="true" />
      <LastExportDate xsi:nil="true" />
      <FlaggedForResend xsi:nil="true" />
    </ProductIdentifiers>
    <ProductName xmlns="http://3ecompany.com/webservices/catalogitemxml">118DA All Purpose Spray Adhesive - 82019 (10.5 oz aerosol)</ProductName>
    <ProductUid xmlns="http://3ecompany.com/webservices/catalogitemxml">2501f87679eb40c5bff24e9e84170ff1</ProductUid>
    <Locations xmlns="http://3ecompany.com/webservices/catalogitemxml">
      <LocationUid>e504e4605e9c4da6a6243d617b45593f</LocationUid>
      <Name>LUS Philadelphia (New Inventory)</Name>
      <ChemicalApprovalStatus>None</ChemicalApprovalStatus>
      <Quantity xsi:nil="true" />
      <LocationPath>American Airlines &gt; PHL &gt; LUS Philadelphia (New Inventory)</LocationPath>
      <ChemicalApprovalConditionalNotes />
      <Notes />
      <ActivatedBy>tehrman</ActivatedBy>
      <ActivatedOn>2016-06-06T11:04:47.193</ActivatedOn>
    </Locations>
    <EeeProductId xmlns="http://3ecompany.com/webservices/catalogitemxml">3319854</EeeProductId>
    <EeeCpcId xmlns="http://3ecompany.com/webservices/catalogitemxml">15071137</EeeCpcId>
    <ConverterData xmlns="http://3ecompany.com/webservices/catalogitemxml" />
    <CreatedBy xmlns="http://3ecompany.com/webservices/catalogitemxml">ondata</CreatedBy>
    <CreatedDate xmlns="http://3ecompany.com/webservices/catalogitemxml">4/25/2016</CreatedDate>
    <IsDeactivated xmlns="http://3ecompany.com/webservices/catalogitemxml">false</IsDeactivated>
    <DeactivatedDate xsi:nil="true" xmlns="http://3ecompany.com/webservices/catalogitemxml" />
  </CatalogItem>
</ArrayOfCatalogItem>
```

The stored procedure which reads from this xml returns a lot of duplicates

This is a rough draft stored procedure, I know I can shorten it further but I'll do it once I figure out everything else.

```
BEGIN

DECLARE @XmlTable TABLE (XMLDATA XML)

INSERT INTO @XmlTable(XMLData)
SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn 
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\AA.Sample.File.LUS.Pilly-oneCI.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://3ecompany.com/webservices/catalogitemxml' as CI)
SELECT 
    --CIVersion = CI.value('@Version', 'int'),
    Identifier = PID.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(9)'),
    Product_Name = MSDSPN.value('(.)[1]','varchar(100)'),
    Revision_Date = RevDt.value('(.)[1]', 'Datetime'),
    Review_Date = RevwDt.value('(.)[1]', 'Datetime'),
    Density = Dy.value('(.)[1]', 'float'),
    Specific_Gravity = SG.value('(.)[1]', 'float'),
    Manufacturer_Name = MN.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(80)'),
    Manufacturer_Address = Mad.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(80)'),
    Manufacturer_City = MCY.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(40)'),
    Manufacturer_State = MST.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(20)'),
    Manufacturer_Postal_Code = MPC.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(20)'),
    CAS_Number = CAS.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(20)'),
    Chemical_Name = CN.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
    Weight_Percent = PC.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    Min_Weight_Percent = MNPC.value('(.)[1]', 'float'),
    Max_Weight_Percent = MXPC.value('(.)[1]', 'float'),
    Container_Size = CSV.value('(.)[1]', 'float'),
    Container_Unit = CSU.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(30)'),
    SARA_Fire = SF.value('(.)[1]', 'bit'),
    SARA_Release = SR.value('(.)[1]', 'bit'),
    SARA_Reactivity = SRY.value('(.)[1]', 'bit'),
    SARA_Acute = SRA.value('(.)[1]', 'bit'),
    SARA_Chronic = SRC.value('(.)[1]', 'bit'),
    EHS = SDV.value('(.)[1]', 'bit'),
   -- TPQ_Pounds = if(SRTX.value('(.)[1]','bit')) return SDV.value('(.)[1]', 'int')) else (return 0),
    Solid = PS.exist('(.)[contains(.,"Solid")]'),
    Liquid = PS.exist('(.)[contains(.,"Liquid")]'),
    Gas = PS.exist('(.)[contains(.,"Gas")]'),
    Container_Code = CTP.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(10)')

FROM
    @XmlTable
Outer APPLY
    XMLData.nodes('/ArrayOfCatalogItem/CatalogItem') AS XT(CI)
OUTER APPLY
    CI.nodes('CI:ProductIdentifiers/CI:Identifier') AS XT2(PID)
OUTER APPLY
    CI.nodes('CI:Msds/CI:MsdsProductName') AS XT3(MSDSPN)
OUTER APPLY
    CI.nodes('CI:Msds/CI:RevisionDate') AS XT4(RevDt)
OUTER APPLY
    CI.nodes('CI:Msds/CI:SdsConfirmationDate') AS XT5(RevwDt)
OUTER APPLY
    CI.nodes('CI:Msds/CI:Properties/CI:Density/CI:Value') AS XT6(Dy)
OUTER APPLY
    CI.nodes('CI:Msds/CI:Properties/CI:SpecificGravity') AS XT7(SG)
OUTER APPLY
    CI.nodes('CI:ManufacturerName') AS XT13(Mn)
OUTER APPLY
    CI.nodes('CI:Msds/CI:MfgContactInfo/CI:MfgAddress') AS XT14(Mad)
OUTER APPLY
    CI.nodes('CI:Msds/CI:MfgContactInfo/CI:MfgCity') AS XT15(MCY)
OUTER APPLY
    CI.nodes('CI:Msds/CI:MfgContactInfo/CI:MfgState') AS XT16(MST)
OUTER APPLY
    CI.nodes('CI:Msds/CI:MfgContactInfo/CI:MfgPostalCode') AS XT17(MPC)
OUTER APPLY
    CI.nodes('CI:Msds/CI:Ingredients/CI:Cas') AS XT18(CAS)
OUTER APPLY
    CI.nodes('CI:Msds/CI:Ingredients/CI:ChemicalName') AS XT19(CN)
OUTER APPLY
    CI.nodes('CI:Msds/CI:Ingredients/CI:Percent') AS XT20(PC)
OUTER APPLY
    CI.nodes('CI:Msds/CI:Ingredients/CI:MinPercent') AS XT21(MNPC)
OUTER APPLY
    CI.nodes('CI:Msds/CI:Ingredients/CI:MaxPercent') AS XT22(MXPC)
OUTER APPLY
    CI.nodes('CI:Msds/CI:FireCodeClassification/CI:Sara/CI:Fire') AS XT8(SF)
OUTER APPLY
    CI.nodes('CI:Container/CI:ContainerSize/CI:Value') AS XT25(CSV)
OUTER APPLY
    CI.nodes('CI:Container/CI:ContainerSize/CI:Units') AS XT26(CSU)
OUTER APPLY
    CI.nodes('CI:Msds/CI:FireCodeClassification/CI:Sara/CI:Pressure') AS XT9(SR)
OUTER APPLY
    CI.nodes('CI:Msds/CI:FireCodeClassification/CI:Sara/CI:Reactivity') AS XT10(SRY)
OUTER APPLY
    CI.nodes('CI:Msds/CI:FireCodeClassification/CI:Sara/CI:Immediate') AS XT11(SRA)
OUTER APPLY
    CI.nodes('CI:Msds/CI:FireCodeClassification/CI:Sara/CI:Delayed') AS XT12(SRC)
CROSS APPLY
    CI.nodes('CI:Msds/CI:Ingredients/CI:Sara313Details/CI:IsSara313Toxic') AS XT23(SRTX)
OUTER APPLY
        CI.nodes('CI:Msds/CI:Ingredients/CI:Sara313Details/CI:ReportingThreshold/CI:Value') AS XT24(SDV)
CROSS APPLY
    CI.nodes('CI:Msds/CI:Properties/CI:PhysicalState') AS XT27(PS)
OUTER APPLY
    CI.nodes('CI:Container/CI:ContainerType') AS XT28(CTP)

END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your attempt there are far to many `APPLYs`. You need them **in cases of nested 1:n only!**

Most of your nestings are *boundled* but `1:1`. You read these values just with a longer `XPath`.

Btw: There was a closing `</HCodes>` missing in your XML.

Your XML

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<ArrayOfCatalogItem xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <CatalogItem Version="1">
    <Container xmlns="http://3ecompany.com/webservices/catalogitemxml">
      <ContainerSize>
        <Value>10.500000000</Value>
        <Units>OunceUS</Units>
      </ContainerSize>
      <ContainerType>Unknown</ContainerType>
      <MarkedForRetail xsi:nil="true" />
    </Container>
    <Documents CultureCode="en" Elink="https://3eonline.com/ImageServer/ImageViewer.aspx?id=3Q%2ffAR8ne%2fvPh6syVnSymkS%2bBDo8OjmbVocxRCMEgeENagNJzc81tOXY0yL87aEPfwnzvlaVmM1mbrA2r7BYXNzA43I%2baZTLYlibHjHcCDI%3d" Format="Msds" DocumentType="Sds" Country="USA" DocumentId="SDS8672822" RevisionDate="2015-05-18T00:00:00" xmlns="http://3ecompany.com/webservices/catalogitemxml" />
    <IsHazardous xmlns="http://3ecompany.com/webservices/catalogitemxml">true</IsHazardous>
    <ManufacturerName xmlns="http://3ecompany.com/webservices/catalogitemxml">Permatex Inc.</ManufacturerName>
    <Msds xmlns="http://3ecompany.com/webservices/catalogitemxml">
      <Elink>https://3eonline.com/ImageServer/ImageViewer.aspx?id=3Q%2ffAR8ne%2fvPh6syVnSymqIuIP5CInA01ZbaRQ9r18GfjipRC2KgVeHKeJd2rplH4f%2b5u6E0coedMiZYmt%2fs1A%3d%3d</Elink>
      <FireCodeClassification>
        <Asphyxiant>false</Asphyxiant>
        <WaterReactive xsi:nil="true" />
        <Hmis Chronic="true" Fire="4" Health="2" Reactivity="0" Special="X" />
        <Nfpa Fire="4" Health="1" Reactivity="0" Special="" />
        <Sara>
          <Delayed>true</Delayed>
          <Fire>true</Fire>
          <Immediate>true</Immediate>
          <Pressure>true</Pressure>
          <Reactivity>false</Reactivity>
        </Sara>
        <DerivedPhysicalState>Aerosol</DerivedPhysicalState>
      </FireCodeClassification>
      <Ingredients>
        <ChemicalName>Hexane</ChemicalName>
        <Cas>000110-54-3</Cas>
        <Percent>30.000000</Percent>
        <PercentMin>10.000000</PercentMin>
        <PercentOperator>LessThanOrEqualTo</PercentOperator>
        <PercentMinOperator>GreaterThanOrEqualTo</PercentMinOperator>
        <PercentUnits>ByWeight</PercentUnits>
        <PercentModifier xsi:nil="true" />
        <MinPercent>10.000000</MinPercent>
        <MaxPercent>30.000000</MaxPercent>
        <Sara313Details>
          <ChemicalKey>110543</ChemicalKey>
          <Deminimus />
          <IsPBT>false</IsPBT>
          <IsSara313Toxic>true</IsSara313Toxic>
          <ReportingThreshold>
            <Value>25000</Value>
            <Units>Pound</Units>
          </ReportingThreshold>
          <SaraChemName>N-HEXANE</SaraChemName>
        </Sara313Details>
        <Sara302Details>
          <ChemicalKey>110543</ChemicalKey>
          <IsSara302Ehs>false</IsSara302Ehs>
        </Sara302Details>
        <OshaPelDetails>
          <ChemicalKey>110543</ChemicalKey>
          <OshaPelChemName>N-HEXANE</OshaPelChemName>
          <Type>Z1</Type>
          <Twa>500</Twa>
          <TwaUnits>unknown unit type</TwaUnits>
          <TwaInMg>1800</TwaInMg>
          <Stel xsi:nil="true" />
          <CeilInPpm xsi:nil="true" />
          <CeilInMg xsi:nil="true" />
          <PeakInPpm xsi:nil="true" />
          <PeakInMg xsi:nil="true" />
        </OshaPelDetails>
        <AcgihTlvDetails>
          <ChemicalKey>110543</ChemicalKey>
          <AcgihTlvChemName>N-HEXANE</AcgihTlvChemName>
          <SkinDesignation>true</SkinDesignation>
          <Sensitizer>false</Sensitizer>
          <SimpleAsphyxiant>false</SimpleAsphyxiant>
          <CarcinogenCategory />
          <YearKnowCarcinogen />
          <ExposureByAllRoutes>false</ExposureByAllRoutes>
          <Twa xsi:nil="true" />
          <TwaInPpm>50</TwaInPpm>
          <StelInPpm xsi:nil="true" />
          <StelInMg xsi:nil="true" />
          <CeilInPpm xsi:nil="true" />
          <CeilInMg xsi:nil="true" />
          <MolecularWeight>86.18</MolecularWeight>
          <TlvBasisCriticalEffect>CNS impair; peripheral neuropathy; eye irr</TlvBasisCriticalEffect>
        </AcgihTlvDetails>
        <AvgPercent>20.000000</AvgPercent>
      </Ingredients>
      <Ingredients>
        <ChemicalName>2-Propanone</ChemicalName>
        <Cas>000067-64-1</Cas>
        <Percent>30.000000</Percent>
        <PercentMin>10.000000</PercentMin>
        <PercentOperator>LessThanOrEqualTo</PercentOperator>
        <PercentMinOperator>GreaterThanOrEqualTo</PercentMinOperator>
        <PercentUnits>ByWeight</PercentUnits>
        <PercentModifier xsi:nil="true" />
        <MinPercent>10.000000</MinPercent>
        <MaxPercent>30.000000</MaxPercent>
        <Sara313Details>
          <ChemicalKey>67641</ChemicalKey>
          <IsPBT>false</IsPBT>
          <IsSara313Toxic>false</IsSara313Toxic>
        </Sara313Details>
        <Sara302Details>
          <ChemicalKey>67641</ChemicalKey>
          <IsSara302Ehs>false</IsSara302Ehs>
        </Sara302Details>
        <OshaPelDetails>
          <ChemicalKey>67641</ChemicalKey>
          <OshaPelChemName>ACETONE</OshaPelChemName>
          <Type>Z1</Type>
          <Twa>1000</Twa>
          <TwaUnits>unknown unit type</TwaUnits>
          <TwaInMg>2400</TwaInMg>
          <Stel xsi:nil="true" />
          <CeilInPpm xsi:nil="true" />
          <CeilInMg xsi:nil="true" />
          <PeakInPpm xsi:nil="true" />
          <PeakInMg xsi:nil="true" />
        </OshaPelDetails>
        <AcgihTlvDetails>
          <ChemicalKey>67641</ChemicalKey>
          <AcgihTlvChemName>ACETONE</AcgihTlvChemName>
          <SkinDesignation>false</SkinDesignation>
          <Sensitizer>false</Sensitizer>
          <SimpleAsphyxiant>false</SimpleAsphyxiant>
          <CarcinogenCategory>A4</CarcinogenCategory>
          <YearKnowCarcinogen />
          <ExposureByAllRoutes>false</ExposureByAllRoutes>
          <Twa xsi:nil="true" />
          <TwaInPpm>250</TwaInPpm>
          <StelInPpm>500</StelInPpm>
          <StelInMg xsi:nil="true" />
          <CeilInPpm xsi:nil="true" />
          <CeilInMg xsi:nil="true" />
          <MolecularWeight>58.05</MolecularWeight>
          <TlvBasisCriticalEffect>URT &amp; eye irr; CNS impair</TlvBasisCriticalEffect>
        </AcgihTlvDetails>
        <AvgPercent>20.000000</AvgPercent>
      </Ingredients>
      <MsdsId>8672822</MsdsId>
      <MsdsMfgName>Permatex USA</MsdsMfgName>
      <MsdsProductName>118Da All Purpose Spray Adhesive 11 oz</MsdsProductName>
      <Properties>
        <PhysicalState>Aerosol</PhysicalState>
        <BoilingPoint>
          <Minimum xsi:nil="true" />
          <Range>EqualTo</Range>
          <Units>Celsius</Units>
          <Value>38.0000</Value>
        </BoilingPoint>
        <FlashPoint>
          <Minimum xsi:nil="true" />
          <Range>EqualTo</Range>
          <Units>Celsius</Units>
          <Value>-18.0000</Value>
        </FlashPoint>
        <MolecularWeight xsi:nil="true" />
        <Ph xsi:nil="true" />
        <SpecificGravity>0.7300</SpecificGravity>
        <VaporDensity xsi:nil="true" />
        <Uel xsi:nil="true" />
        <Lel xsi:nil="true" />
        <BoilingPointInCelsius>
          <Minimum xsi:nil="true" />
          <Range>EqualTo</Range>
          <Units>Celsius</Units>
          <Value>38</Value>
        </BoilingPointInCelsius>
        <FlashPointInCelsius>
          <Minimum xsi:nil="true" />
          <Range>EqualTo</Range>
          <Units>Celsius</Units>
          <Value>-18</Value>
        </FlashPointInCelsius>
        <BoilingPointInFahrenheit>
          <Minimum xsi:nil="true" />
          <Range>EqualTo</Range>
          <Units>Fahrenheit</Units>
          <Value>100.4</Value>
        </BoilingPointInFahrenheit>
        <FlashPointInFahrenheit>
          <Minimum xsi:nil="true" />
          <Range>EqualTo</Range>
          <Units>Fahrenheit</Units>
          <Value>-0.399999999999999</Value>
        </FlashPointInFahrenheit>
      </Properties>
      <RevisionDate>2015-05-18T00:00:00</RevisionDate>
      <MsdsRevListId>3836824</MsdsRevListId>
      <SdsConfirmationDate>2015-05-18T00:00:00</SdsConfirmationDate>
      <ClassificationCompleted>true</ClassificationCompleted>
      <CasCompleted>true</CasCompleted>
      <PropertiesCompleted>true</PropertiesCompleted>
      <Locale>en</Locale>
      <DocumentFormat>Msds</DocumentFormat>
      <Country>USA</Country>
      <MsdsLanguage>en</MsdsLanguage>
      <MsdsRegion>UnitedStates</MsdsRegion>
      <SdsNotRequired>false</SdsNotRequired>
      <MfgContactInfo>
        <MfgAddress>6875 Parkland Boulevard</MfgAddress>
        <MfgCity>Solon</MfgCity>
        <MfgState>Ohio</MfgState>
        <MfgCountry>United States</MfgCountry>
        <MfgPostalCode>44139</MfgPostalCode>
        <MfgPhoneCountryCode />
        <MfgPhoneAreaCode>440</MfgPhoneAreaCode>
        <MfgPhoneNumber>914-3571</MfgPhoneNumber>
        <MfgPhoneExtension />
        <MfgFaxCountryCode />
        <MfgFaxAreaCode>440</MfgFaxAreaCode>
        <MfgFaxNumber>914-3500</MfgFaxNumber>
        <MfgFaxExtension />
        <MfgEmail>denise.boyd@permatex.com</MfgEmail>
        <MfgWebUrl>http://www.permatex.com</MfgWebUrl>
      </MfgContactInfo>
      <GhsClassification>
        <SignalWord>None</SignalWord>
        <SignalWordText>Danger</SignalWordText>
        <Pictograms>
          <Code>GHS02</Code>
        </Pictograms>
        <Pictograms>
          <Code>GHS07</Code>
        </Pictograms>
        <Pictograms>
          <Code>GHS08</Code>
        </Pictograms>
        <HazardClasses>
          <HazardClassText>Flammable aerosol.</HazardClassText>
          <CategoryText>Category 1</CategoryText>
          <HazardClassPhraseTextID>92876</HazardClassPhraseTextID>
          <CategoryPhraseTextID>93598</CategoryPhraseTextID>
          <InternalHazardClassPhraseID>4059</InternalHazardClassPhraseID>
          <InternalHazardClassPhraseLangCode>en</InternalHazardClassPhraseLangCode>
          <InternalCategoryPhraseID>4082</InternalCategoryPhraseID>
          <InternalCategoryPhraseLangCode>EN</InternalCategoryPhraseLangCode>
        </HazardClasses>
        <PCodes>
          <SequenceNumber>401</SequenceNumber>
          <Pcode>P405</Pcode>
          <PcodeText>Store locked up.</PcodeText>
          <PcodeSubTypeText>Storage</PcodeSubTypeText>
          <PcodePhraseTextID>91288</PcodePhraseTextID>
          <InternalPcodePhraseID>4009</InternalPcodePhraseID>
          <InternalPcodePhraseLangCode>EN</InternalPcodePhraseLangCode>
        </PCodes>
        <HCodes>
          <SequenceNumber>1</SequenceNumber>
          <Hcode>H315</Hcode>
          <HcodeText>Causes skin irritation.</HcodeText>
          <HcodeSubTypeText>HealthHazard</HcodeSubTypeText>
          <HcodePhraseTextID>91544</HcodePhraseTextID>
          <InternalHcodePhraseID>4017</InternalHcodePhraseID>
          <InternalHcodePhraseLangCode>EN</InternalHcodePhraseLangCode>
        </HCodes>
        <SignalWordPhraseTextID>236050</SignalWordPhraseTextID>
        <InternalSignalWordPhraseId>22738</InternalSignalWordPhraseId>
        <InternalSignalWordPhraseLangCode>EN</InternalSignalWordPhraseLangCode>
      </GhsClassification>
      <TransportationClassificationCompleted xsi:nil="true" />
      <WasteCompleted xsi:nil="true" />
      <ExtendedSds>false</ExtendedSds>
      <TransportationExceptionClassificationCompleted xsi:nil="true" />
      <BestAvailable>false</BestAvailable>
    </Msds>
    <ProductIdentifiers xmlns="http://3ecompany.com/webservices/catalogitemxml">
      <Identifier>M007628</Identifier>
      <Source>CPN</Source>
      <FirstExportDate xsi:nil="true" />
      <LastExportDate xsi:nil="true" />
      <FlaggedForResend xsi:nil="true" />
    </ProductIdentifiers>
    <ProductName xmlns="http://3ecompany.com/webservices/catalogitemxml">118DA All Purpose Spray Adhesive - 82019 (10.5 oz aerosol)</ProductName>
    <ProductUid xmlns="http://3ecompany.com/webservices/catalogitemxml">2501f87679eb40c5bff24e9e84170ff1</ProductUid>
    <Locations xmlns="http://3ecompany.com/webservices/catalogitemxml">
      <LocationUid>e504e4605e9c4da6a6243d617b45593f</LocationUid>
      <Name>LUS Philadelphia (New Inventory)</Name>
      <ChemicalApprovalStatus>None</ChemicalApprovalStatus>
      <Quantity xsi:nil="true" />
      <LocationPath>American Airlines &gt; PHL &gt; LUS Philadelphia (New Inventory)</LocationPath>
      <ChemicalApprovalConditionalNotes />
      <Notes />
      <ActivatedBy>tehrman</ActivatedBy>
      <ActivatedOn>2016-06-06T11:04:47.193</ActivatedOn>
    </Locations>
    <EeeProductId xmlns="http://3ecompany.com/webservices/catalogitemxml">3319854</EeeProductId>
    <EeeCpcId xmlns="http://3ecompany.com/webservices/catalogitemxml">15071137</EeeCpcId>
    <ConverterData xmlns="http://3ecompany.com/webservices/catalogitemxml" />
    <CreatedBy xmlns="http://3ecompany.com/webservices/catalogitemxml">ondata</CreatedBy>
    <CreatedDate xmlns="http://3ecompany.com/webservices/catalogitemxml">4/25/2016</CreatedDate>
    <IsDeactivated xmlns="http://3ecompany.com/webservices/catalogitemxml">false</IsDeactivated>
    <DeactivatedDate xsi:nil="true" xmlns="http://3ecompany.com/webservices/catalogitemxml" />
  </CatalogItem>
</ArrayOfCatalogItem>';
```

And here's the query

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://3ecompany.com/webservices/catalogitemxml' AS i --Default on inner levels...
                  ,'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' AS xsd
                  ,'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS xsi)
SELECT ci.value('@Version','int') AS CatalogVersion
      ,ci.value('(i:Container/i:ContainerSize/i:Value)[1]','decimal(15,9)') AS ContainerSizeValue
      ,ci.value('(i:Container/i:ContainerType)[1]','varchar(max)') AS ContainerType
      --more values from Container-node
      ,ci.value('(i:Documents/@CultureCode)[1]','varchar(10)') AS DocumentCultureCode
      --more attributes from Documents
      --more elements on the same level
      ,ci.value('(i:Msds/i:Elink)[1]','varchar(max)') AS Msds_Elink
      ,ci.value('(i:Msds/i:FireCodeClassification/i:Asphyxiant)[1]','bit') AS Msds_FireCodeClassification_Asphyxiant
      --more elements here
      ,ig.value('(i:ChemicalName)[1]','varchar(max)') AS Ingredients_ChemicalName
      --more values for ingredients here
      ,ci.value('(i:Msds/i:MsdsId)[1]','bigint') AS Msds_Id
      --more elements here

      --and many more following this approach

FROM @xml.nodes('/ArrayOfCatalogItem/CatalogItem') AS A(ci)
CROSS APPLY A.ci.nodes('i:Msds/i:Ingredients') AS B(ig)
```

Comment: This is brilliant. I deleted most of the xml since its a huge one. I had another answer from mark in a similar question as well. thx